# How to use "+" character as a String

Tags: arduino-uno, string

Well I am trying to save phone number as a string. For ease of use I want to add "+" character programmatically. Like this:

```
String cepNo ="+" + "901234567";
```

But program gives this error.

```
exit status 1
invalid operands of types 'const char [2]' and 'const char [13]' to binary 'operator+'
```

How to add "+" beginning of the string.

Comment: A string literal isn't a String. You can't concatenate them like that. This is C, not BASIC.

Comment: The arduino error is on the +, not the "+".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add C strings (i.e. NUL-terminated arrays of `char`) with the
`+` operator. It only works with `String` objects. You can, though, add
a String object and a C-string, because in this case the compiler
implicitly converts the C string into a String object:

```cpp
String phone_number = "901234567";
phone_number = "+" + phone_number;
```

The last line is interpreted by the compiler as

```cpp
phone_number = String("+") + phone_number;
```

That being said, I encourage you to try to avoid String objects if
possible. These use dynamic memory allocation which carries the risk of
heap fragmentation. The same thing can be achieved with plain C strings:

```cpp
char phone_number[] = "901234567";
char full_phone_number[strlen(phone_number) + 2];
strcpy(full_phone_number, "+");
strcat(full_phone_number, phone_number);
```

Note the size of the second string: `strlen(phone_number) + 2`. You need
one extra `char` for the `+` sign, and another one for the NUL string
terminator.

Now, with C strings you can do better, and avoid copying: reserve enough
room in an array for the full number (“+” included), and then fill the
digits starting from the second slot in the `char` array. You can then
add the `+` sign later:

```cpp
char phone_number[16];
strcpy(phone_number + 1, "901234567");
phone_number[0] = '+';
```

Although I personally would write the “+” sign and a NUL while
initializing the array:

```cpp
char phone_number[16] = "+";
strcat(phone_number, "901234567");
```

Answer (score 2):

use `String cepNo = String("+") + "901234567";`
or
`String a = "+"; String cepNo = a + "901234567";`

Comment: Or, simply don't use the + operator.